# TYPO3 RTE Image Upload is not visible when using

Tags: typo3, typoscript, rich-text-editor, rte, typo3-flow

I use templavoila and TYPO3 4.5.29. I created a template in FCE. and added mapped text area.
I can see the rich text editor but I can't use some of the features. like Image Upload/Page Break.. etc..

Attaching the FCE form and Backend screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3DataStructure>
    <meta type="array">
        <langDisable>1</langDisable>
    </meta>
    <ROOT type="array">
        <tx_templavoila type="array">
            <title>ROOT</title>
            <description>Select the HTML element on the page which you want to be the overall container element for the template.</description>
        </tx_templavoila>
        <type>array</type>
        <el type="array">
            <field_tab1_title type="array">
                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                    <title>Tab 1 Title</title>
                    <sample_data type="array">
                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                    </sample_data>
                    <eType>rte</eType>
                    <preview></preview>
                    <TypoScript><![CDATA[
10 = TEXT
10.current = 1
10.parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc_RTE]]></TypoScript>
                </tx_templavoila>
                <TCEforms type="array">
                    <label>Tab 1 Title</label>
                    <config type="array">
                        <type>text</type>
                        <cols>48</cols>
                        <rows>5</rows>
                        <softref>*</softref>
                    </config>

<defaultExtras>richtext[*]</defaultExtras>

                </TCEforms>
            </field_tab1_title>
        </el>
    </ROOT>
</T3DataStructure>
```

[image]

I dont know what when wrong in my congfiguration.

What wrong with FCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the RTE via the Extension Manager. Go to the configuration panel of the extension rtehtmlarea and set 'Default configuration settings' to Demo. Now you can see all features of the RTE.

[Here](http://www.typo3lexikon.de/typo3-tutorials/rte.html) is a quite good tutorial for configuring the RTE in TYPO3 (in german).